# How touse onBackPresee method in Android?

Tags: java, android

I'm implementing media player in Android. When I run the application my music is playing and when I click the back button my Activity is exit. But I want when I click back button my music is going on pause state and activity wants to finish and when I restart my application my music is on resume state. I used back onBackPressed() and the only activity is finish music, not pause. How can I do this?

Here is my code.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.audio);
            init();


            mp=MediaPlayer.create(Audio_Activity.this,R.raw.ennamo_yadho);
            Log.e("Song is playing","in  Mediya Player ");
            mp.setLooping(false);
            mp.start();
            System.out.println("B4 button Click!!!!");

            if(mp.isPlaying())
            {
                if(mp!=null)
                {


                    length=mp.getCurrentPosition();
                    mp.seekTo(length);
                    mp.start();
                }

            }


            mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() 
            {

                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) 
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    //finish(); Activity is exist
                    mp.stop();
                    mp.release();
                    btnChapter.setEnabled(true);
                    System.out.println("Music is over and Button is enable !!!!!!");
                }
            });



    public void onBackPress()
        {
            super.onBackPressed();
            if(mp.isPlaying())
            {
                if(mp!=null)
                {
                    mp.pause();
                    finish();
                    System.out.println("Back Button Is Call and Audio Is on Pause state ");

                }
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: what do you want achieve?

Answer (score 0):

you should remove

> super.onBackPressed();

and then finish your Activity yourself and pause your music ...

**Edit** : you should override **onBackPressed()** not onBackPress() try this code below and check if mp.pause get called on pressing back button with break points :

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed ()
{
        if(mp.isPlaying())
        {
            if(mp!=null)
            {
                mp.pause();
                this.finish();
                System.out.println("Back Button Is Call and Audio Is on Pause state ");

            }
        }
}
```

Comment: just remove super.onBackPressed() and if you want to finish your activity on pressing back button call this.finish()

Comment: But i want as an when my activity is finish it immediately my audio music is also going  to pause state .My activity is finish but my music is not going to on pause state.Music is still playing even activity is exit.

Comment: Please give me solution for pause the music on back button also i removed super.onBackPressed() but music is still playing.How can i do this.